# How to switch between two levels in a data.frame in R?

Tags: r

I have a data frame

```
>id=c(1,2,1,1,2);type=c("B","S","S","B","B")
>temp=data.frame(id, type)
  id type
1  1    B
2  2    S
3  1    S
4  1    B
5  2    B
```

So the type has two levels: B and S. For every row, if id==2, I would like to switch the level and let its id=1, and get something like this:

```
  id type
1  1    B
2  1    B
3  1    S
4  1    B
5  1    S
```

I've tried to code:

```
 >for (i in 1:nrow(temp)) {
   if (temp[i,1]==2) 
     {if (temp[i,2]=="B") temp[i,2]=="S" 
      else temp[i,2]=="B";temp[i,1]=1;} }
```

But it didn't work. It returned this:

```
  id type
1  1    B
2  1    S
3  1    S
4  1    B
5  1    B
```

temp[i,1] has changed but temp[i,2] remains the same. How can I fix it? And is there any simpler way to do this because my code seems very clumsy? Thanks in advance. -Natalia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work.  Although, maybe there is a simpler way.

```
id=c(1,2,1,1,2); type=c("B","S","S","B","B")
temp=data.frame(id, type, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

temp$type2 <- ifelse(temp$type == 'B', 'S', 'B')
temp
#  id type type2
#1  1    B     S
#2  2    S     B
#3  1    S     B
#4  1    B     S
#5  2    B     S

temp2 <- temp[,1:2]   
temp2$type <- ifelse(temp$id   ==   2, temp$type2, temp$type)
temp2$id   <- 1
temp2

#  id type
#1  1    B
#2  1    B
#3  1    S
#4  1    B
#5  1    S
```

Comment: Thanks. And do I have to use "stringsAsFactors = FALSE"? Because actually my data frame is read from a csv file. temp=data.frame(id, type) is just an example...

Comment: It do work in this case but seems doesn't in my real data.frame..Here is the problem: `>temp$type2 [1] "S" "S" "B" "B" "B" "B"` `>temp$type
 [1] B B S S S S Levels: B S` But I've already use this  `>temp=temp2=as.data.frame(test2,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`.

Comment: @Natalia I am not sure I understand.  Consider editing your original post to include a more complex example at the bottom in which my code does not work.  Also post the desired result with that more complex example and I will see whether I can edit my code to return the correct answer for both example data sets.  If the problem is that I am using a variable name (`temp2`) that you are already using for something else, then just change my variable name from `temp2` to something unique, to something you are not already using for something else.

Comment: Thanks, I think it's not `temp2`'s problem. I've added `temp$id=as.character(temp$id)` so that your code work perfectly now. Thank you so much for `ifelse` because I didn't know it before! It's really useful.